# virsh capabilities does not include qemu or kvm

Tags: kvm, libvirt, virsh

I am new  to Libvirt and Qemu.I have installed Libvirt 7.1.0 and qemu-kvm 4.2.0 on centos 8.
I configured and built libvirt based on instructions from
https://libvirt.org/compiling.html.

But when i tried to create a VM using virsh it shows the following error:

`# virsh create /home/abc.xml`

`error: Failed to create domain from /home/abc.xml             error: invalid argument: could not find capabilities for arch=x86_64 domaintype=kvm`

When i check the hypervisor capabilities ,it doest show qemu or kvm in guest domain type.

`#virsh capabilities`

````
.....................................
     </host>

      <guest>
        <os_type>exe</os_type>
        <arch name='x86_64'>
          <wordsize>64</wordsize>
          <emulator>/usr/local/libexec/libvirt_lxc</emulator>
          <domain type='lxc'/>
        </arch>
      </guest>

      <guest>
        <os_type>exe</os_type>
        <arch name='i686'>
          <wordsize>32</wordsize>
           <emulator>/usr/local/libexec/libvirt_lxc</emulator>
          <domain type='lxc'/>
        </arch>
      </guest>

    </capabilities>```

    I have restarted libvirt to get the qemu support,but  it is not shown in capabilities list.What will be the problem?
Thanks for the help in advance
````

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem from the answers given by libvirt-users mailing list.
I didnt pass prefix while building.
So I tried

`meson build -Dsystem=true`

It worked for me.Now virsh shows kvm and qemu in its capabilities and could create a new VM using virsh create.

Thanks ...